# How do I get the file of my sqlite db with cordova?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

I have a cordova App and I need to back up my db file and get it later, I tryed to use the cordova-plugin-dbcopy plugin but it doesn't work, I receive the message 404 - Db not found

code to copy db to device storage:

```
window.plugins.sqlDB.copyDbToStorage('Raptor8', 0, cordova.file.externalRootDirectory +'/', true,
    function (a,b) {
    alert('ok!');
}, function (a, b) {
    alert('Erro!');
});
```

Anyone have any sugestions or other ways to do this?

Comment: That db file will not be in the external root directory. If you supply a path to a function you could check before if the file exists in that path too. Or is that path the destination dir? What are the other parameters?

Comment: the first parameter is the name of db, second its an useless parameter for android, third is the path where the plugin will save the db.

Comment: this plugin should copy the db from the intern path of the app to the device storage